# axios.patch / axios.put is not working in Vue and Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, vue.js, axios

I have this code in my vue file

```
saveProfile() {
    axios.patch('/api/pegawai/' + this.id, {
         data: this.data
    })
    .then(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);            
    });
}
```

and in my laravel controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
     return $this->sendResponse('request retrieved');
}

public function sendResponse($message){
    $response = [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => $message,
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 200);
}
```

when i run the vue file to pass the data to the controller **it should** give me a json response to the browser console with the following value

```
{
  'success' : true,
  'message' : 'request retrieved'
}
```

but **currently it gives** me an error `500 internal server error` through the browser console. I get the same result if I replace `axios.patch` with `axios.put`.

--- *What I Have Tried* ---

I have tried to do `axios.post` and `axios.get` with the same scenarios as `axios.patch` and both working properly. Controller for post and get:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    return $this->sendResponse('request retrieved');
}

public function index(){  
    return $this->sendResponse('request retrieved');
}
```

Comment: So what is the actual response content coming back with the 500? It should contain a clue to the problem.

Comment: Could you please show the route declaration for these APIs? @Rafid

Comment: what error are you getting ? it will be easy if you add error in your question

Comment: @rkj the console only gives me `500 internal server error` without other information

Comment: @AdreAstrian this is the route declaration `Route::resource('pegawai', 'Pegawai\PegawaiAPIController');`. the file name of the controller is `PegawaiAPIController.php`

Comment: check `laravel.log` file, it will have details

Answer (score 22, accepted):

actually `HTTP PUT` is not recognized by html standard. try to do hack like so:

```
saveProfile() {
    axios.post('/api/pegawai/' + this.id, { // <== use axios.post
         data: this.data,
         _method: 'patch'                   // <== add this field
    })
    .then(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);            
    });
}
```

Comment: what if i'm using formData?

Comment: @FernandoTorres `formDataInstance.append('_method', 'patch')`