# Laravel PATCH Request doesn't read Axios form data

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm trying to send a Axios PATCH request to Laravel 5.6 api.
My request contains a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Laravel's api endpoint doesn't read any of the sent data.

**ReactJS code**

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("photo", this.state.photo);
// append another data ....

const headers = { 
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'enctype' : 'multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token 
}

axios({
  method : "PATCH",
  baseURL: this.baseURL,
  url    : url,
  params : params,
  data   : data,
  headers: headers,
}).then(response => {
  return response
})
```

**Laravel patch request**

```
public function update(Request $request, $planId)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    dd($data);
}
```

Laravel request prints an empty array `[]`.

Comment: Have you checked what the data sent to the server contains?

Comment: yes, i use reactjs and redux and i print data after sent it from view to action and print it in the action and it exist but when send it to laravel it doesn't read it

Comment: @AbeerElhout please check in your network tab to make sure the data is sent to the endpoint

Comment: And have you checked through your network console which data is **really** sent? Additionally, try to debug further which data reaches the server - you could use another raw PHP script to simply dump that data

Comment: @phaberest yes, I did this check and data exist

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sad but true, when requesting from the browser it happens that Laravel doesn't properly answer to PATCH or PUT requests.

A quick solution might be using a `POST` and adding `_method: PATCH` as post parameter.

Please try with this updated code

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("_method", 'PATCH');
data.append("photo", this.state.photo);
// append another data ....

const headers = { 
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'enctype' : 'multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token 
}

axios({
  method : "POST",
  baseURL: this.baseURL,
  url    : url,
  params : params,
  data   : data,
  headers: headers,
}).then(response => {
  return response
})
```

Another example of the same issue can be found in [axios.patch / axios.put is not working in Vue and Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170564/axios-patch-axios-put-is-not-working-in-vue-and-laravel)

Comment: thanks a bunch... After spending hours on this issue.

Comment: I've been there too my friend ;)

Comment: thanks so much for this...i've been struggling with this since 4 hours too

Answer (score 0):

Because HTTP PUT is not recognized by HTML standard.

You need to add POST type of method only but for update you can add a small flag with POST request for a PUT/PATCH type of operation.

```
axios.post(url, {      // <== use axios.post
 data: data,
 _method: 'patch'      // <== add this field
})
```