# Laravel array $request->all() empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, axios

I'm working on a shopping cart with Laravel.

I have :

Routes :

```
Route::post('/panier/ajouter', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
Route::patch('/panier/{product}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
```

View :

```
<table class="table" id="table-shoppingcart">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center" id="item-title-shoppingcart"></th>
                        <th class="text-center" id="size-title-shoppingcart">Taille</th>
                        <th class="text-center" id="quantity-title-shoppingcart">Quantité</th>
                        <th class="text-center" id="price-title-shoppingcart">Prix</th>
                        {{-- <th class="text-center" id="delete-title-shoppingcart"></th> --}}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (Cart::content() as $product)
                    <tr>

                        <th><img class="text-center item-content-shoppingcart" src="{{ $product->model->image }}"></th>
                        <td class="text-center td-table-shoppingcart size-content-shoppingcart">S</td>
                        <td class="td-table-shoppingcart quantity-content-shoppingcart">
                            <select name="quantity" class="custom-select text-center quantity" id="quantity" data-id="{{ $product->rowId }}">
                                @for ($i = 0; $i < 5 + 1 ; $i++)
                                <option id="quantity-option" {{ $product->qty == $i ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $i }}</option>
                            @endfor
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center td-table-shoppingcart price-content-shoppingcart">{{ getPrice($product->subtotal()) }}</td>

                    </tr>
            @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Ajax request :

```
$("#quantity").change(function(){
    const classname = document.querySelectorAll('#quantity')
    Array.from(classname).forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element);
        let id = element.getAttribute('data-id')
        axios.patch(`/panier/${id}`, {
            quantity: this.value
        })
        .then(function (response) {
           // console.log(response);
           console.log("refresh");
            $("#table-shoppingcart").load(location.href + " #table-shoppingcart");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("erreur");
           // console.log(error);
        });
    })
});
```

I need to get the quantity in my controller so i try :

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->json()->all();
        Log::info($data);
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Cart Quantity Has Been Updated']);
    }
```

But when i try to get a $data value, my array is empty like this in my log :

```
[2020-02-22 10:49:46] local.INFO: array ()
```

I tryed to change :

```
$data = $request->json()->all();
```

To

```
$data = $request->all();
```

But same problem.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you plz add your route file ?

Comment: oh yes sorry !  Its done

Comment: I think that because `axios.patch` is now working properly refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170564/axios-patch-axios-put-is-not-working-in-vue-and-laravel

Comment: I tryed this. Same error but i see in my array the row_method but not quantity. So i tryed to change quantity:this.value to quantity:5 to test. And i get the row quantity now. So this problem is quantity:this.value in ajax request. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: `this` is referring local scope in JS . since you are using Jquery I don't see the point of using `this`. you need to inject the event to you change function and from there you can get the value. let me know if need you need post it answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel cheats with `PUT/PATCH/DELETE` etc requests. These need to be `POST` requests with the extra variable `'_method'` set to the request type (e.g.) `PATCH`.

Comment: Now its working but my on change working only the first time ?

Comment: Use `$('body').on('change','#quantity',function(){...});`instead

Comment: ooh you are the boss !! Juste the problem its when i have more then one product in my cart. When i change the quantity on the first product, the second product quantity change too. How i can fix this ?

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.